# "Permission denied" when trying to use RVM with Cron

Tags: cron, ruby, rvm

I am trying to employ the method descibed [here](https://rvm.io//integration/cron/).

My crontab:

```
# m h  dom mon dow   command
@reboot /home/qe2user/.rvm/environments/ruby-1.9.3-p125 /home/qe2user/Ruby/test/prog.rb > /home/qe2user/Ruby/test/crondebug.log 2>&1
```

My ruby prog:

```
doit = true
while doit
    File.open('/home/qe2user/Ruby/test/test.txt','a') {|f| f.write(Time.now.to_s + "\n")}
    doit = false
end
```

the output in crondebug.log:

```
/bin/sh: /home/qe2user/.rvm/environments/ruby-1.9.3-p125: Permission denied
```

I issued "chmod u+x prog.rb", then rebooted again, but got the same results.

prog.rb, such as it is, does write to the file when I just run it from the command line.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is `/home/qe2user/.rvm/environments/ruby-1.9.3-p125` executable?  `ls -la /home/qe2user/.rvm/environments/ruby-1.9.3-p125`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The file you are executing is `/home/qe2user/.rvm/environments/ruby-1.9.3-p125`, not `/home/qe2user/Ruby/test/prog.rb`.

Therefore, you have to make the first one executable:

```
chmod u+x /home/qe2user/.rvm/environments/ruby-1.9.3-p125
```

This is, of course, assuming that `ruby-1.9.3-p125` is owned by the crontab's user.

Comment: Well, that did away with the "Permission denied".  Thank you.  Now my problem is, the file, "test.txt" is not getting written. Sigh.